# How to detect network failure in sockets Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, buffer

I am trying to write internal transport system.
Data should be transferred from client to server using net sockets.
It is working fine except handling of network issues.
If I place firewall between client and server, on both sides I will not see any error, so data will continue to fill kernel buffer on client side.
And if I will restart app in this moment I will lose all data in buffer.

Question:
Do we have any way to detect network issues?
Do we have any way to get data back from kernel buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node js exposes the low level socket api to you very directly. I'm assuming that you are using a TCP socket to send and receive data.

One way to ensure that there is an active connection between the client and server is to send heartbeat signals back and forth. If you fail to receive a heartbeat from the server while sending data, you can assume that the connection failed.

As for the second part of your question: There is no easy way to get data back from kernel buffers. If losing the data will be a problem, I would make sure to write it to disk.